# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

Tags: rosdep, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the command from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source) tutorial

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
```

I get

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

image_geometry:  No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]
urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS version [precise]   
collada_parser: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS version [precise]   
image_view: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]  
rosconsole_bridge: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
cv_bridge: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]
class_loader: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
image_rotate: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]
roslz4: No definition of [lz4] for OS version [precise]
collada_urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS version [precise]
roslisp: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]  
rosbag_storage: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
stereo_image_proc: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]  
urdf_parser_plugin: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS version [precise]
cpp_common: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
geometric_shapes: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
camera_calibration: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [precise]
tf2: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS version [precise]
```

I am installing this on an Ubuntu server running 12.04, and when I try to manually install the packages one by one:

```
sudo apt-get install liburdfdom-headers-dev
```

I get

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package liburdfdom-headers-dev is not
> available, but is referred to by
> another package.   This may mean that
> the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or   is only available from
> another source
>
> E: Package 'liburdfdom-headers-dev'
> has no installation candidate

I tried installing not using the source but got equally frustrating errors there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211474/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies:/) by [sethdrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22817/sethdrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-06-16**:
The problem with OpenCV is that we packaged our own version of OpenCV on Precise, but after Precise we get it from apt-get. So Jade (which came after Precise) try's to get it from apt-get, but it's not there.

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2018-04-03**:
I had a similar problem when running `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y` on `Mint 18.3`, then I executed `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --os=ubuntu:xenial` and worked for me.

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2018-04-03**:
I found this tip `--os=ubuntu:xenial` here: https://gitter.im/mavlink/mavros/archives/2015/02/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will probably not be the answer you're looking for, but Jade is not officially supported on Ubuntu Precise. Unresolvable dependencies are exactly the kind of issue you run into then. From the page you linked:

> ROS Jade supports **Trusty, Utopic, and Vivid**. Other platforms are possible to use but are **not expected to work out of the box**.

[REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#jade-turtle-may-2015-may-2017) confirms this: "Support for: Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), Ubuntu Utopic (14.10), Ubuntu Vivid (15.04)".

The `packages.ubuntu.com` page for [liburdfdom-headers-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liburdfdom-headers-dev) shows that it is only available for Trusty and up, hence the error you encountered trying to install it using `apt-get`.

---

Edit: alternatives to attempting a full from-source install could be using a chroot (see [wiki/InstallingIndigoInChroot](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot)) or using docker [with ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/docker).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1